# Unit testing a method called during initialization?

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, testing

I have a class like the following:

```
class Positive(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self._validate_item(item)
        self.item = item

    def _validate_item(self, item):
        if item <= 0:
            raise ValueError("item should be positive.")
```

I'd like to write a unit test for `_validate_item()`, like the following:

```
class PositiveTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_validate_item_error(self):
        self.assertRaises(
            ValueError,
            Positive._validate_item,
            0
        )
```

Unfortunately, this won't work because the unit test only passes 0 to the method, instead of a class instance (for the `self` parameter) and the 0.  Is there any solution to this other than having to test this validation method indirectly via the `__init__()` of the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not using self in the method's body, it's a hint that it might not need to be a class member.  You can either move the _validate_item function into module scope:

```
def _validate_item(item):
    if item <= 0:
        raise ValueError("item should be positive.")
```

Or if it really has to stay in the class, the mark the method static:

```
class Positive(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self._validate_item(item)
        self.item = item

    @staticmethod
    def _validate_item(item):
        if item <= 0:
            raise ValueError("item should be positive.")
```

Your test should then work as written.

Comment: I like this answer. If you feel the need to write tests for _validate_item() on its own, chances are it actually belongs on its own.

Comment: staticmethods are mostly pointless in Python, in that case use a classmethod!

Comment: I wouldn't use the `@classmethod` decorator here for the same reason I wouldn't define it as an instance method.  There's no use of `cls`.  Given my druthers, I'd make it a private function at module scope.

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating an instance of Positive. How about

```
Positive()._validate_item, 0
```

Comment: This code raises a TypeError because `Positive.__init__()` is missing the `item` argument.

Comment: This shows you you are trying to test the implementation "_validate_item", not the interface. I think testing `Positive(0)` is *much* better than testing `_validate_item(0)`.

Comment: Above comment is to @gotgenes

Answer (score 1):

Well, _validate_item() is tested through the constructor. Invoking it with a null or negative value will raise the ValueError exception.

Taking a step back, that's the goal no ? The "requirement" is that object shall not be created with a zero or negative value.

Now this is a contrived example, so the above could not be applicable to the real class ; another possibility, to really have a test dedicated to the _validate_item() method, could be to create an object with a positive value, and then to invoke the validate_item() on it.